# Removed obsolete DAO 3.6 reference and broke 480 lines of code that referenced DAO.[Something]

Tags: vba, ms-access, dao

I don't know how to replace DAO. in the lines of code that were using it.
If the Microsoft Office 16.0 Access Object Library has replaced DAO then how do your reference items in that library?

I have tried not replacing DAO. and everything else I can see in the type ahead window for a Dim statement.
Dim rs as XXX.Recordset.

Comment: DAO is default, don't need to explicitly select library and DAO references should still work. Does for me. Did you mean "Microsoft Access 16 Object Library" or "Microsoft Office 16.0 Access database engine Object Library" as that is how they are listed in References? Just tested and if I remove the latter, DAO no longer works.

Comment: Me too just now. :)  That was nerve wracking.  I must have unchecked Microsoft Office 16.0 Access database engine Object Library by mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct - you do not need nor require the DAO reference. However, if this is a mdb, then the DAO reference can and should remain.

So, in references, you should see this:

[image]

Now, to be fair, in a lot of cases the Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library can often be skipped, but I do recommend that you include that reference.

So, in effect, to "replace" and "not require" the DAO 3.6 engine?

You should have the Microsoft Office 16.0 database engine Object.

Ensure that is selected. And now in VBA code, try a debug->compile from the menu.

You should be good to go.